# pass variable into postgresql's date extract() function?

Tags: function, postgresql, date, parameters, extract

I can't work out how to pass a variable into the postgresql extract function like:

```
select 'day' as i;
extract(i from a_date)
```

that gives me

> ERROR:  timestamp with time zone units
>   "i" not recognized

If I can pass in a string, extract('day' from a_date), why not a variable ?

Comment: Could you show us the entire script? You have to fetch the result from the SELECT into the next query where you need this result. Or is this about pl/pgsql?

Comment: If you're writing a function, then the assignment operation is either `SELECT INTO i 'day';` or `i := 'day';` Your example does not provide enough context to properly answer the question.

Comment: how about using an IN parameter: select extract($1 from a_date) - that yields a syntax error

Answer (score 5):

ANSI SQL doesn't support parameters there. Use a date_part function instead.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

```
postgres=# select extract(day from current_timestamp);
 date_part 
-----------
        23
(1 row)

postgres=# select date_part('day', current_timestamp);
 date_part 
-----------
        23
(1 row)
```

Comment: ok, but how about passing in a variable ? like select date_part(my_variable, current_timestamp);